# Bootstrap collapse not opening/closing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was working on a new webpage everything is working well but the collapse's will not open or close I included jQuery en BS3 modals, smooth scrolling are working.

The page what http://codenamelungo.net/wiki.php

Comment: Include the code here.!

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to assume that because the Bootstrap js is coming in as text/rocketscript instead of text/javascript, the browser doesn't know how to handle it.

I would see if you can disable it for that script since it's already coming through a CDN and is already minimized.

Reference stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/how-does-cloudflares-rocket-loader-actually-work-and-how-can-a-developer-ensur

Add `data-cfasync="false"` to the script tag in manual mode.

Comment: found the script that causes the problem see here: http://www.bootply.com/NBmwhDLgxg is there a possibility to only smooth scroll when a link in the #sidebar is clicked or a link in .navbar is clicked?